# Normalization with a column has a redundancy and fully depended on the primary key

Tags: database-design, database-normalization

I'm studying now the Normalization, And I know about the three types of Normalization.
But I'm still confused about something!

Let me give an example

```
|- primary -|

product_name | price | category |
--------------------------------|
any name     | 236   | food     |
another name | 36    | clothes  |
test name    | 586   | food     |
a name       | 1036  | food     |
```

Now `category` column has a redundancy, but dependent on what I understand about normalization there's no problem in that, because `category` column **fully depended** on the primary key like `2N` and it doesn't have **transitive dependency** like `3N`.

But I still see a redundancy that will make a modification anomalies.

I see It should be like

```
|- primary -|

product_name | price | category |
--------------------------------|
any name     | 236   | 1        |
another name | 36    | 2        |
test name    | 586   | 1        |
a name       | 1036  | 1        |



id | category name |
-------------------|
1  | food          |
2  | clothes       |
```

Please if someone can clear this to me I'll be so glad.

And sorry for my bad English or any grammar mistakes or something.

Comment: What is your question? PS That has nothing to do with normalization. You have replaced values of one type by values of another type, then added a new unnecessary table. Find out what "normalization" is.

Comment: @philipxy please check the conversation below. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you "see" is not a "redundancy" and your proposed alternative has exactly the same "redundancy" because now you have the number one mentioned three distinct times.

The only reason your proposed alternative is "better" is if there is a need for "food" and "clothes" to also be displayable in other languages and we would get something like

```
id | lang | category name |
--------------------------|
1  | EN   | food          |
2  | EN   | clothes       |
1  | ES   | comidas       |
```

but your original problem does not state such a thing, and there is nothing wrong with your example as far as normalization is concerned.

Comment: My problem with this kind of "redundancy" is.., assume you have 10,000 rows with `food` category and suddenly you should edit `food` word to `junk food` for example, that's will make you update 10,000 rows, but with separate the `category` column in own table you will need to update only one row, now you will avoid modification anomalies like update 10,000 rows.
For that I see It should be separated.

but that's has no problem with normalization like you said, right!

Comment: "Updating 10000 rows" is ***not*** an "anomaly".  It is a consequence of design choices, perhaps an unfortunate consequence but it is most certainly a design antipattern to apply this "separation" strategy blindly for every attribute around, merely for the lame excuse of "suppose we ever need to change entire sets of rows".  Changing entire sets of rows is what relational technology was ***invented for***.

Comment: I understand your opinion now, that make thing clear to me. And I didn't mean to separate every column to table when we find a duplication, but In case like this, when It frequently category name changes every short period, so I have seen It's better to separate them to make operation like update faster. Anyway, thank so much for your time.